# how to get value from postdata in jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, jqgrid

how to use data in postdata in jqgrid? below is my code. the value asset_id is there when I alert it, but how to get the value in PHP?

```
edittype:"select",
width: 200,
editoptions: {
maxlength:30,
dataUrl : "/build/15",
postData: function (rowid) {
  return {
    // action: "getState",
    asset_id: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "asset_id")
  };
},
```

this is in my PHP code.

```
function build($program){

    $data = $this->input->post("asset_id"); // i get object error


    // I try to echo the value of post data in here, but I get object error.
}
```

i try to put the value in postdata in my controller.

Comment: post the entire code including what you may have in php. we need to see more.

Comment: @unixmiah i dont start my php program yet, but above is what i have i mind.

Comment: You want us to start it for you?

Comment: no @Tpojka, I just want to know how to read the data from post data into php. i really don't have any idea how to do it. i try to find the example, but can't really find it. i try $this->input->post("asset_id"), but get error, i try use $_POST["asset_id"], but object error.

Comment: Is that all code? Where is rest of code? Post model code too.